# Does LimeSurvey work on PHP 7?

Tags: limesurvey

Trying to run latest LimeSurvey from Github (2.50_plus_160731) on Ubuntu Xenial in a docker container.  Currenlty running an older version in a container on Ubuntu Trusty works fine.

The installation section of the manual just says "Minimum PHP 5.3.3 or later, however we recommend PHP 5.5.x".

Does anyone know if LimeSurvey is supposed to run on PHP 7?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

LimeSurvey run on PHP7, if not : it's a bug.

exemple : https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/blob/f20abfe8d11d3dc1210b36982e3565a6d7fbbb52/docs/release_notes.txt#L433 or https://github.com/LimeSurvey/LimeSurvey/commit/6dce75c84a3c37c8c5a6cc29f81cb1375c429630